# How to draw a vertical area chart?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, charts

How to draw vertical area in d3?
something like I drew in red color:

[image]

What is the best approach here? I can't find any examples on the internet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In fact, as you say, most of examples of area charts (I'd say virtually all of them) use a *horizontal* area, that is, a version where the baseline is horizontal.

However, it's very easy to create a *vertical* area chart (that is, with a vertical baseline) using D3. To do so, one has to use the way less known `x1` and `x0` methods of the [area generator](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape/blob/master/README.md#area).

What happens is that, since almost all examples online are horizontal area charts, you only see `x`, `y1` and `y0` as the methods of the area generator. However, the same way `x` alone sets `x0` to the value and `x1` to `null`, `y` sets `y0` to the value and `y1` to `null`.

That being said, you just need to set the vertical baseline with `x0`. Check this example:

```js
const svg = d3.select("svg");
const data = [0, 80, 20, 210, 130, 270, 30, 110, 130, 0];
const areaGenerator = d3.area()
  .x0(0)
  .x1(d => d)
  .y((_, i) => i * 15)
  .curve(d3.curveMonotoneY)
const area = svg.append("path")
  .attr("d", areaGenerator(data))
  .style("fill", "teal");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

In short, these are the methods you need:

**Horizontal area chart**:

- `x`: position in the baseline
- `y1`: distance from baseline
- `y0`: baseline

**Vertical area chart**:

- `y`: position in the baseline
- `x1`: distance from baseline
- `x0`: baseline

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have been looking for this solution for hours!